# Specify namespace using helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Running the below command results in an error. Even if I manually delete the namespace before.

```
$ helm-2.7.2 --kube-context nine-ml-dev install erst/jenkins-devops-package --namespace sud-devops --name sud-devops --version 1.11.0 --values nine-ml-dev/sud-jenkins-server.yaml 

Error: release sud-devops failed: namespaces "sud-devops" already exists
```

But if I leave out the --namespace it goes to default. What's the proper way to specify a namespace for my package?

Comment: Hacky workaround: sometimes Helm gets confused and `helm del --purge sud-devops` helps.  Not an actual answer though.

Comment: Did you delete the release using `helm delete <release name>` or just deleted only the namespace where the app was deployed. Note that helm store release information in a ConfigMap. So, if you don't delete the release , it is not removed from the ConfigMap. It will have history that will tell that  release `A` was deployed in  namespace `N`. So, it will show you already exist error if you again try to deploy `A` in namespace `N` even if you had deleted namespace `N` meanwhile.

Comment: do you have a namespace specified in that yaml file?